# Why are these characteristics of the FT-180 highlighted?

Tags: aircraft-performance, jet-engine, turbojet, model-aircraft

I have been checking the FT-180 engine used to establish speed record for remotely controlled aircraft (i.e. model airplanes). There are some specific features highlighted on the [manufacturer site](https://www.ultimate-jets.net/products/ft-180-jet-engine). I'm not specialist of turbojets, but I don't understand **why** those characteristics are highlighted:

- *They are at the top of innovation with unique features like carbon fiber cowling, Genx type chevron exhaust system and full Inconel internals.*
  ===> Since all these materials are explicited, what is the specific element behind? How do they prevent another company to build a similar engine?
- *All aluminium and steel design: no plastic parts are present on the engine except for the carbon fiber inlet cowl.*
  ===> Why is this important no to have plastic part? I thought that plastic was a light and weather resistant material, so a good one for a remotely controlled aircraft?
- *Genx type chevron exhaust cone .*
  ===> Genuine question: why is this important? Does it give higher performance to the engine?
- Also, with link to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99084/what-were-the-main-differences-between-whittles-british-turbojet-and-von-ohain): This engine is a axial engine, not a centrifugal one, am I right?

Comment: This is a question about an engine for *model airplanes*-- I hope my edit made that clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

> All aluminium and steel design: no plastic parts are present on the
> engine except for the carbon fiber inlet cowl. ===> Why is this
> important no to have plastic part? I thought that plastic was a light
> and weather resistant material, so a good one for a remotely
> controlled aircraft?

Because plastics have a relatively low melting point, and jet engines get hot.